Unstable attempt at mean-preserving quadratic interpolation
I've been looking for an efficient mean-preserving calculation for quadratic interpolation.  It doesn't seem to exist.  So I tried a bare-bones basic system of linear equations in python and it's numerically unstable even if the input array is completely flat.
The model: every bin of data is of width 1.  The value of the bin is identical to the integral of a quadratic polynomial over the bin, such that
Int(a_i+b_ix+c_ix^2,{dx,x-1/2,x+1/2})=data[x,i, x=i]=a_i+b_ix+c_i*(x^2+1/12).
In addition I set values to match between proximate pairs, so that
a_i+b_i*(x+1/2)+c_i*(x+1/2)^2=a_{i+1}+b_{i+1}*(x+1/2)+c_{i+1}*(x+1/2)^2

and so on for the slope.
The knots of the splines are tied at +-1/2, where the negative end of the first set is left dangling, and I define the boundary conditions on the last set.  So for a dataset of length n, I've got 3n equations and 3n variables.  np.linalg.solve() can take it!
The results are unstable for all input datasets, and immediately unstable for the input dataset [1,2,3]. The system of equations don't get anywhere close to being solved.
I expected integro_quadratic_spline_orig to return I after being given the output of integro_quadratic_spline(I).  But alas, it comes nowhere near.
def integro_quadratic_spline(I):
    # Number of intervals
    n = len(I)

    # Initialize coefficients
    a = np.zeros(n)
    b = np.zeros(n)
    c = np.zeros(n)

    # Set up the system of equations
    A = sp.sparse.csr_array((3*n, 3*n))
    B = np.zeros(3*n)

    # Integral conditions


    #ALL CONDITIONS. First line solve, 2nd line continuity
    for i in range(0,n-1):
        A[3*(i),3*(i):3*(i)+6]=[1,(i),(i)**2+1/12,0,0,0] #condition that the integral over the bin matches the original bin value
        A[3*(i)+1,3*(i):3*(i)+6]=[0,1,2*(i+1/2),0,-1,-2*(i+1/2)] #condition that the slope at the right edge of the current bin matches the slope at the left edge of the next bin
        A[3*(i)+2,3*(i):3*(i)+6]=[1,i+1/2,(i+1/2)**2,-1,-(i+1/2),-(i+1/2)**2] #condition that the value at the right edge of the current bin matches the value at the left edge of the next bin
        B[3*(i)]=I[i] #Value of the integral
        B[3*(i)+1]=0 #matching condition,  a'-b'=0
        B[3*(i)+2]=0 #matching condition, a-b=0
    #below is same as above, but for trailing end.  
    i=i+1    
    A[3*(i),3*(i):3*(i)+3]=[1,(i),(i)**2+1/12]
    A[3*(i)+1,3*(i):3*(i)+3]=[0,1,2*(i+1/2)]
    A[3*(i)+2,3*(i):3*(i)+3]=[1,i+1/2,(i+1/2)**2]
    B[3*(i)]=I[i]
    B[3*(i)+1]=0
    B[3*(i)+2]=I[i]

    # Solve the system

    coeffs = sp.sparse.linalg.spsolve(A, B)
    print(np.allclose(np.dot(A.toarray(), coeffs), B))

    # Extract coefficients
    for i in range(n):
        a[i] = coeffs[3*i]
        b[i] = coeffs[3*i+1]
        c[i] = coeffs[3*i+2]

    return a, b, c


def integro_quadratic_spline_return(coeffs, mag):
    original_length = len(coeffs[0])
    new_length=original_length*mag
    newplot=np.empty(new_length)
    for i in range(original_length):
        for j in range(int(mag)):
            newplot[mag*i+j]=coeffs[0][i]+coeffs[1][i]*(i+j/mag-1/2)+coeffs[2][i]*(i+j/mag-1/2)**2

    return newplot

def integro_quadratic_spline_orig(coeffs):
    original_length = len(coeffs[0])
    newplot=np.empty(original_length)
    for i in range(original_length):
        newplot[i]=coeffs[0][i]+coeffs[1][i]*(i)+coeffs[2][i]*((i)**2-12)

    return newplot


You have a somewhat complex description of splines, bins, etc. Can you draw a diagram?

Where does your current implementation attempt to preserve the mean?

"mean-preserving" needs more definition. Do you mean that the mean of every interpolated segment curve must equal the value of its respective segment input value? Or something else?

Must the interpolated curve pass through the input point? If not, this isn't really interpolation.

Let me finish the comment above....mis-post
2. It's commented in code
3. Yes, that's exactly what I mean.  Int( a +b z+ c z^2, {z, x-1/2, x+1/2})=segment value
4. If the slope, value matching and integral matching conditions are met w/ the edge boundary condition, the curve will pass through the input point.

Since you haven't answered any questions, here's a series of wild guesses; first I demonstrate with nonlinear methods:
Nonlinear form
import functools

import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import minimize, NonlinearConstraint


def split_params(params: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
    return params.reshape((3, -1))


def spline_evaluate(
    x: np.ndarray,
    a: np.ndarray,
    b: np.ndarray,
    c: np.ndarray,
) -> np.ndarray:
    return a*x**2 + b*x + c


def spline_diff_evaluate(
    x: np.ndarray,
    a: np.ndarray,
    b: np.ndarray,
) -> np.ndarray:
    return 2*a*x + b


def spline_integral_evaluate(
    x: np.ndarray,
    a: np.ndarray,
    b: np.ndarray,
    c: np.ndarray,
) -> np.ndarray:
    return a*x**3/3 + b*x**2/2 + c*x


def spline_cost(
    params: np.ndarray,
) -> float:
    """
    Rudimentary cost based on total order-1 and order-2 coefficients ("prefer a flat curve")
    """
    a, b, c = split_params(params)
    return a.dot(a) + b.dot(b)


def c0_continuity_residuals(
    params: np.ndarray,
    inner_bounds: np.ndarray,
) -> np.ndarray:
    a, b, c = split_params(params)
    y_left = spline_evaluate(
        x=inner_bounds, a=a[:-1], b=b[:-1], c=c[:-1],
    )
    y_right = spline_evaluate(
        x=inner_bounds, a=a[1:], b=b[1:], c=c[1:],
    )
    return y_left - y_right


def c1_continuity_residuals(
    params: np.ndarray,
    inner_bounds: np.ndarray,
) -> np.ndarray:
    a, b, c = split_params(params)
    yd_left = spline_diff_evaluate(
        x=inner_bounds, a=a[:-1], b=b[:-1],
    )
    yd_right = spline_diff_evaluate(
        x=inner_bounds, a=a[1:], b=b[1:],
    )
    return yd_left - yd_right


def get_means(
    params: np.ndarray,
    inner_bounds: np.ndarray,
) -> np.ndarray:
    a, b, c = params.reshape((3, -1))[:, 1:-1]
    x0 = inner_bounds[:-1]
    x1 = inner_bounds[1:]
    return (
        spline_integral_evaluate(x=x1, a=a, b=b, c=c) -
        spline_integral_evaluate(x=x0, a=a, b=b, c=c)
    )/(x1 - x0)


def get_boundary_conditions(
    params: np.ndarray,
    x: np.ndarray,
) -> np.ndarray:
    a, b, c = split_params(params)
    return spline_evaluate(
        x=x[[0, -1]], a=a[[0, -1]], b=b[[0, -1]], c=c[[0, -1]],
    )


def solve_spline(x: np.ndarray, y: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
    """
    Solve for spline sections, one per input point, where each section takes the form
    ax**2 + bx + c
    i.e. a quadratic spline with C1 continuity. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_(mathematics)
    This is not interpolation, because the splines do not intersect the input points; they preserve
    section means equal to the input points.
    """

    inner_bounds = 0.5*(x[:-1] + x[1:])
    a0 = np.zeros_like(y)
    b0 = np.zeros_like(y)
    c0 = y.copy()
    x0 = np.concatenate((a0, b0, c0))
    epsilon = 1e-12

    c0_continuity = NonlinearConstraint(
        fun=functools.partial(c0_continuity_residuals, inner_bounds=inner_bounds),
        lb=-epsilon, ub=epsilon,
    )

    c1_continuity = NonlinearConstraint(
        fun=functools.partial(c1_continuity_residuals, inner_bounds=inner_bounds),
        lb=-epsilon, ub=epsilon,
    )

    mean_preservation = NonlinearConstraint(
        fun=functools.partial(get_means, inner_bounds=inner_bounds),
        lb=y[1:-1] - epsilon, ub=y[1:-1] + epsilon,
    )
    boundary_conditions = NonlinearConstraint(
        fun=functools.partial(get_boundary_conditions, x=x),
        lb=y[[0, -1]] - epsilon, ub=y[[0, -1]] + epsilon,
    )

    result = minimize(
        fun=spline_cost, x0=x0,
        constraints=(
            c0_continuity, c1_continuity, mean_preservation, boundary_conditions,
        ),
    )
    if not result.success:
        raise ValueError(result.message)
    return split_params(result.x)


def plot(
    x: np.ndarray,
    y: np.ndarray,
    a: np.ndarray,
    b: np.ndarray,
    c: np.ndarray,
) -> plt.Figure:
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.scatter(x, y)

    xres = np.linspace(start=x[0], stop=0.5*(x[0] + x[1]), num=51)
    ax.plot(xres, spline_evaluate(xres, a[0], b[0], c[0]))
    xres = np.linspace(start=0.5*(x[-2] + x[-1]), stop=x[-1], num=51)
    ax.plot(xres, spline_evaluate(xres, a[-1], b[-1], c[-1]))

    for x0, x1, x2, ai, bi, ci in zip(
        x[:-2], x[1: -1], x[2:],
        a[1:-1], b[1:-1], c[1:-1],
    ):
        xleft = 0.5*(x0 + x1)
        xright = 0.5*(x1 + x2)
        xres = np.linspace(start=xleft, stop=xright, num=51)
        yres = spline_evaluate(xres, ai, bi, ci)
        ax.plot(xres, yres)

    return fig


def demo() -> None:
    rand = np.random.default_rng(seed=0)
    x = np.arange(10)
    y = rand.uniform(low=-1, high=1, size=x.size)
    a, b, c = solve_spline(x, y)
    plot(x, y, a, b, c)
    plt.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    demo()


Linear form
This is equivalent:
import typing

import numpy as np
import scipy.sparse as sp
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import minimize, LinearConstraint


def split_params(params: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
    return params.reshape((3, -1))


def spline_evaluate(
    x: np.ndarray,
    a: np.ndarray, b: np.ndarray, c: np.ndarray,
) -> np.ndarray:
    return a*x**2 + b*x + c


def spline_cost(params: np.ndarray) -> float:
    """
    Rudimentary cost based on total order-1 and order-2 coefficients ("prefer a flat curve")
    """
    a, b, c = split_params(params)
    return a.dot(a) + b.dot(b)


def generate_constraints(
    x: np.ndarray, y: np.ndarray,
) -> typing.Iterator[LinearConstraint]:
    n = x.size
    inner_bounds = 0.5*(x[:-1] + x[1:])

    # C0 continuity:
    # a0x**2 - a1x**2 + b0x - b1x + c0 - c1 == 0
    yield LinearConstraint(
        A=sp.diags_array(
            (
                inner_bounds**2, -inner_bounds**2,
                inner_bounds, -inner_bounds,
                np.ones(n), -np.ones(n),
            ),
            offsets=(0, 1, n, n+1, 2*n, 2*n+1),
            shape=(n-1, 3*n),
        ),
        lb=0, ub=0,
    )

    # C1 continuity:
    # dy1/dx == dy2/dx
    # 2a0x - 2a1x + b0 - b1 == 0
    yield LinearConstraint(
        A=sp.diags_array(
            (
                2*inner_bounds, -2*inner_bounds,
                np.ones(n), -np.ones(n),
            ),
            offsets=(0, 1, n, n+1),
            shape=(n-1, 3*n),
        ),
        lb=0, ub=0,
    )

    # Mean preservation:
    # (int_x0x1 ax**2 + bx + c dx)/(x1 - x0) == y
    # ax1**3/3 - ax0**3/3 + bx1**2/2 - bx0**2/2 + cx1 - cx0 == y(x1 - x0)
    lbub = y[1:-1]*(inner_bounds[1:] - inner_bounds[:-1])
    yield LinearConstraint(
        A=sp.diags_array(
            (
                (inner_bounds[1:]**3 - inner_bounds[:-1]**3)/3,
                (inner_bounds[1:]**2 - inner_bounds[:-1]**2)/2,
                inner_bounds[1:] - inner_bounds[:-1],
            ),
            offsets=(1, 1+n, 1+2*n),
            shape=(n-2, 3*n),
        ),
        lb=lbub, ub=lbub,
    )

    # Boundary conditions:
    # ax**2 + bx + c == y
    yield LinearConstraint(
        A=sp.coo_array(
            (
                (   # data
                    x[ 0]**2, x[ 0], 1,
                    x[-1]**2, x[-1], 1,
                ),
                (   # coordinates
                    (   # y
                        0, 0, 0,
                        1, 1, 1,
                    ),
                    (   # x
                        0,     n,       2*n,
                           n-1,   2*n-1,    3*n-1,
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
        lb=y[[0, -1]], ub=y[[0, -1]],
    )


def solve_spline(x: np.ndarray, y: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
    """
    Solve for spline sections, one per input point, where each section takes the form
    ax**2 + bx + c
    i.e. a quadratic spline with C1 continuity. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_(mathematics)
    This is not interpolation, because the splines do not intersect the input points; they preserve
    section means equal to the input points.
    """
    a0 = np.zeros_like(y)
    b0 = np.zeros_like(y)
    c0 = y.copy()
    x0 = np.concatenate((a0, b0, c0))

    result = minimize(
        fun=spline_cost, x0=x0,
        constraints=generate_constraints(x=x, y=y),
    )
    if not result.success:
        raise ValueError(result.message)
    return split_params(result.x)


def plot(
    x: np.ndarray, y: np.ndarray,
    a: np.ndarray, b: np.ndarray, c: np.ndarray,
) -> plt.Figure:
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.scatter(x, y)

    xres = np.linspace(start=x[0], stop=0.5*(x[0] + x[1]), num=51)
    ax.plot(xres, spline_evaluate(xres, a[0], b[0], c[0]))
    xres = np.linspace(start=0.5*(x[-2] + x[-1]), stop=x[-1], num=51)
    ax.plot(xres, spline_evaluate(xres, a[-1], b[-1], c[-1]))

    for x0, x1, x2, ai, bi, ci in zip(
        x[:-2], x[1: -1], x[2:],
        a[1: -1], b[1: -1], c[1: -1],
    ):
        xleft = 0.5*(x0 + x1)
        xright = 0.5*(x1 + x2)
        xres = np.linspace(start=xleft, stop=xright, num=51)
        yres = spline_evaluate(xres, ai, bi, ci)
        ax.plot(xres, yres)

    return fig


def demo() -> None:
    rand = np.random.default_rng(seed=0)
    x = np.arange(10)
    y = rand.uniform(low=-1, high=1, size=x.size)
    a, b, c = solve_spline(x, y)
    plot(x, y, a, b, c)
    plt.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    demo()


This looks like you inferred what I was after.  Thank you for the effort in writing down the linear and nonlinear solves.  Excellent proof of principle.  If I want to deploy integral-preserving quadratic splines I'll probably need to learn how to use knots to calculate these things quickly.

In quadratic splines with C1 continuity (derivatives match), a perturbation of one point causes similarly-sized changes over the whole curve.  If you want to set the value of bin means instead of end points, it's worse, and changes grow exponentially.
For this kind of problem, you should probably use cubic splines with C2 continuity (first and second derivatives match).  In these splines, perturbations of one point decay quickly and only have significant effects on a small part of the curve.

Thanks, this describes exactly what I see!  I’ll report back if cubic fixes the situation.

Ended up being a singular matrix...I think the bottom line is I have to learn about knots to do this correctly with linear ops.
